# Error in Configuring Azure Storage Account after using Retry Policies

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, retrypolicy

This is my code to Configure Azure Storage Account

```
public CloudTableClient ConfigureStorageAccount()
{
        var storageCred = new StorageCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SASToken"]);

        CloudTableClient = new CloudTableClient(
                        new StorageUri(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageAccountUri"])), storageCred);



        var backgroundRequestOption = new TableRequestOptions()
        {
            // Client has a default exponential retry policy with 4 sec delay and 3 retry attempts
            // Retry delays will be approximately 3 sec, 7 sec, and 15 sec
            MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
            // PrimaryThenSecondary in case of Read-access geo-redundant storage, else set this to PrimaryOnly
            LocationMode = LocationMode.PrimaryThenSecondary,


        };

        CloudTableClient.DefaultRequestOptions = backgroundRequestOption;

        return CloudTableClient;
}
```

When I specify `backgroundRequestOption` I am getting an error **The Uri for the target storage location is not specified. Please consider changing the request's location mode.**

When I don't specify `backgroundRequestOption` I don't get any error. Where do I need to specify this URI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify both PrimaryUri and SecondaryUri if LocationMode.PrimaryThenSecondary is chosen.

Comment: But where do I need to specify them?

Comment: new StorageUri(primaryUri, secondryUri)